# How to pass parameter using Jquery Ajax function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Controller:-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(string Content)
{
    var result = _repo.Save(Content);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

JS:-

```
$("#saveTree").on("click", function () {
var tree = $("#dvTree").jstree(true).get_json();
var url = '/Home/Save';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(tree) ,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        alert('saved');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('failed');
    }
});

});
```

The problem is tree paramater I am passing to Controller method Save, it comes as null. tree variable is not blank it has value.

How do i pass the value of tree to Save Method?

Comment: So what do you get when you console.log(tree)  before running the ajax call?

Comment: @John: This is what tree variable value before ajax call.  [Object { id="1", text="Root node 222", icon=true, more...}]

Comment: I think you might need to convert the object to json

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i fixed it... See the how I am passing parameter in 'data:'.

```
$("#saveTree").on("click", function () {
var tree = $("#dvTree").jstree(true).get_json();
var url = '/Home/Save';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: "{ 'tree':'" + JSON.stringify(tree) + "'}",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        alert('saved');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('failed');
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Great stuff. you do not require the quotes, ie this would work too:  `data: {tree: JSON.stringify(tree)}`. Or declare the object before like:  `var dataToSend = {tree:JSON.stringify(tree)};` Then simply pass the object to the ajax call:  `$.ajax({    url: url,    type: 'POST',    data: dataToSend, cache...`  This would allow you to control the vars a little easier than directly in the ajax handler.